# Font Awesome with easyAutocomplete plugin

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, easyautocomplete

I have a form in which I want to show the input text field and submit on the same line. The input text field has two FontAwesome icons which I want to show inside the text field. I can style the form as I want when I don't use the easy Autocomplete plugin. But when I activate the **[easyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/)** plugin, the styling goes haywire.

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="">
  <span class="fa fa-map-marker my-fa"></span>
  <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="search-input" class="s" placeholder="Enter your Postcode" autocomplete="off">
  <img id="slider-loading" class="loading" src="https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/02/05/gps2.gif" />
  <input type="hidden" value="profile" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
  <input type="hidden" value="country" name="taxonomy" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="GO" class="submit btn" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var options = {

  data: ["Cyclops", "Storm", "Mystique", "Wolverine", "Professor X", "Magneto"],

  theme: "dark"
};

$("#search-input").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

CSS:

```
.searchform {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.searchform input[type="text"] {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px -3px 0px 0px;
  text-indent: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.searchform input[type=text],
.searchform input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.searchform input[type=text]:focus {
  border: none;
}

.searchform input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #f70808;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c60606;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c60606;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c60606;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.searchform input[type="submit"],
.searchform input[type="text"] {
  line-height: normal !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.my-fa {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #f70808;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  margin-left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
}

#slider-loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  right: 35px;
}
```

I want to show the map icon on the left of the input text field and and the loading spinner on the right of the input text field.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdht1cgw/)** - with easyAutocomplete plugin

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9d8ctcd/)**  - without the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following code to your CSS:

```
.easy-autocomplete{
    display:inline;
}
```

I think it gives you the desired outcome.

The plugin wraps the input in a `div` which by default have `display:block` and it throws the other elements out of line.

You may need to adjust the padding/margin to your preference.

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdht1cgw/1/)

Comment: Thanks. That did it!