# Width override of easyAutocomplete plugin inside input-group-addon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, easyautocomplete

I have an input box in a form. I am using the easyautocomplete plugin in this input box. When I have input box outside the `input-group-addon` the input box has proper width. But, when I add it inside the `input-group-addon`, the width is reduced/collapsed. (See screenshots)

**HTML** *With* `input-group-addon`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
  <label for="taskname">Task Name</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-anchor"></i></span>
    <input class="form-control" id="taskname" name="taskname" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo h($dataset['taskname']); ?>">
  </div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Select Task name from auto suggestion or type your own </small>
</div>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

**HTML** *Without* `input-group-addon`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
  <label for="taskname">Task Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="taskname" name="taskname" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo h($dataset['taskname']); ?>">
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Select Task name from auto suggestion or type your own </small>
</div>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

**Javascript**

```
$("#taskname").easyAutocomplete(tasknameoption);
var tasknameoption = {
  url: "/task/tasklistapi.php",
  getValue: "tasklistname",
  adjustWidth: false,
  requestDelay: 500,
  list: {
    maxNumberOfElements: 10,
    match: {enabled: true},
    onSelectItemEvent: function() {
      var value = $("#taskname").getSelectedItemData().iscomp;
      $("#iscomp").val(value).trigger("change");
    }
  }
};
```

When the above javascript is commented, the form looks as below
[image: SC]

Things I have Tried (but did not work):

1. Adding `adjustWidth: false` in the options as per [Github](https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete/issues/154)
2. Added `inline` CSS as per [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47194613/4050261) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056626/4050261)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the EasyAutocomplete plugin wraps the `<input class="form-control">` into an additional `<div class="easy-autocomplete">` element. With that modification it breaks the Bootstrap markup necessary for proper `input-group` styling. Unfortunately, I did not find an option for EasyAutocomplete to control how it changes the *DOM*.

In order to overcome this, you have two workarounds that I can think of.

- You could modify the Bootstrap *css* to address the new markup. The easiest way to do this would be to recompile the modified *scss* files into a new *css*. However this could also lead to an error prone result.
- The second option however is to further modify the markup a bit with javascript.

I think the latter one is far more the easiest way to do it, so I demonstrate that in the example below.

```js
// Init `easyAutocomplete`
var tasknameoption = {
    adjustWidth: false,
    data: ["blue", "green", "pink", "red", "yellow"]
};
$("#taskname").easyAutocomplete(tasknameoption);

// Fixing markup
$('.easy-autocomplete').closest('.input-group').each(function(i, inputGroup) {
    $(inputGroup).removeClass('input-group');
    $autocomplete = $(inputGroup).find('.easy-autocomplete');
    $(inputGroup).find('.input-group-addon').prependTo($autocomplete);
    $autocomplete.addClass('input-group');
});
```

```css
.easy-autocomplete-container {
    top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
    <label for="taskname">Task Name</label>
    
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" id="taskname" name="taskname" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <small class="form-text text-muted">Select Task name from auto suggestion or type your own </small>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Based on your initial markup, I guess you are using Bootstrap 4 **Beta 2**. It is important to note that **Beta 3** is available, and changes include the styling of the input group component too. So, with the most recent beta version the markup and the “reset” script would look like as below.

```js
// Init `easyAutocomplete`
var tasknameoption = {
    adjustWidth: false,
    data: ["blue", "green", "pink", "red", "yellow"]
};
$("#taskname").easyAutocomplete(tasknameoption);

// Fixing markup
$('.easy-autocomplete').closest('.input-group').each(function(i, inputGroup) {
    $(inputGroup).removeClass('input-group');
    $autocomplete = $(inputGroup).find('.easy-autocomplete');
    $(inputGroup).find('.input-group-prepend').prependTo($autocomplete);
    $autocomplete.addClass('input-group');
});
```

```css
.easy-autocomplete-container {
    top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
    <label for="taskname">Task Name</label>
    
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

        <input class="form-control" id="taskname" name="taskname" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <small class="form-text text-muted">Select Task name from auto suggestion or type your own </small>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Note: As you can see in the examples, it is still required to set `adjustWidth: false` for EasyAutocomplete options. Also, there is a fix for the class `.easy-autocomplete-container` to display properly.

Comment: Your code works perfectly if I have just one autocomplete text box on a page. When I have more than 1 it does not work. Any suggestion for this? I am now using latest stable 4.0 version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is easier than that. 
Just add classes to the initializer.
Example:

```
var options = {
    data: ["Cyclops", "Storm", "Mystique", "Wolverine", "Professor X", "Magneto"],
    theme: "dark", **cssClasses: 'col'**
};
$("#theme").easyAutocomplete(options);
```